# Adds the first element of linked list list_1 as a last element of linked list list_2 and removes it from list_1

Tags: java

For example, if `list_2 = {5, 6, 7, 8}` and `list_1 = {9, 10, 11, 12}`, then:
`Addtolist2(list_2, list_1)` will change `list_2 to {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}` and change `list_1` to `{10, 11, 12}`. Note that you should not create new lists in this method.

```
public class ListNode {
    int data;
    ListNode next;
}

public class List {
     ListNode header;
}
```

This what I tried:

```
public static void Addtolist2(list_2, List_1) {
    ListNode p = l2.header.next;

    while(p != null) {
        p = p.next;
    }

    p = l1.header.next;
    ListNode q = l1.header.next;

    if (l1.header.next.next != null) {
        q = l1.header.next.next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like this (you might have to change a few things)

```
public static void Addtolist2(List list2, List list1) {
    // Find last node in list2
    ListNode lastEl = list2.header;
    while(lastEl != null) {
        lastEl = lastEl.next;
    }

    // Take the first element of list1
    ListNode firstEl = list1.header;

    // Add new element to list2 in last
    ListNode newEl = new ListNode();
    newEl.data = firstEl.data;
    lastEl = newEl;

    // Remove first element of list1 (replace with second)
    list1.header = firstEl.next;
}
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: This really helped me a lot , I can't thank you enough really god bless you and I added this statement ==> newEl.next = null;

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> lst1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(5, 6, 7, 8));
List<Integer> lst2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(9, 10, 11, 12));
System.out.println("lst1 = " + lst1 + " lst2 = " + lst2);
Integer moved = lst2.get(0);
lst2.remove(0);
lst1.add(moved);
System.out.println("lst1 = " + lst1 + " lst2 = " + lst2);
```

Comment: What if i wanna write it as a method from these two classes ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainClass
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    LinkedList<Integer> list1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    list1.add(5);
    list1.add(6);
    list1.add(7);
    list1.add(8);

    LinkedList<Integer> list2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    list2.add(9);
    list2.add(10);
    list2.add(11);
    list2.add(12);

    Integer element = list2.getFirst();
    list1.addLast(element);
    list2.removeFirst();

    System.out.println("First List:");
    System.out.print(list1);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Second List: ");
    System.out.print(list2);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. but i am trying to write a method from these two classes above :)

Comment: Ok if you want to make your own implementation of the idea for linked list you can see which methods you will need. As you can see from above you need 1. Add element on a certain place (index), 2. remove element on certain place (index) and then you can easily make the method for removing and adding elements as I show you. Just split your task on smaller ones. For the implementation of a List and ListNode I can not help you right now. Maybe someone can give you idea or you can search on internet. Good luck!